# Word 2007 spelling and grammar check error

Tags: windows-vista, microsoft-office-2007, spell-check

I have so many errors in spelling ang grammer in my document. But when I click on ABC button, it says that apelling check is complete and returns no errors. I have full installation of Microsoft Office 2007 on vista. What is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem got solved after I installed full version. Earlier I installed by customization.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

Your office profile might be corrupted. Try this following soluton:

You need to make some changes in your Windows registry in order to fix the issue:
1. HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Shared Tools\Proofing Tools\1.0
AND/OR
2. HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\12.0\ApplicationName(Word, Outlook, Exel, etc.)

Rename these keys by going to Start->Run, regedit, in registry editor navigate to the following keys and rename (right click) them to:

1. HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Shared Tools\Proofing Tools\1.0old
2. HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\12.0\Outlookold (example for Outlook spell check) OR HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\12.0\Wordold (for Word spell check)

Reboot Windows and restart Office. MS Office will recreate the keys automatically.

Notes: Creating a new profile does the same thing. If your spell check works under a new profile, your current_user registry is corrupted, and this fix should work fine.

[source](http://www.dbuggr.com/smallwei/microsoft-office-word-2007-2003-spell-checker-working-typing/)

Answer (score 1):

> First, click the Microsoft Office
>   Button, close it, and see if spell
>   check begins to work. (Believe it or
>   not, there's a slight bug with spell
>   check and the Microsoft Office Button,
>   you need to click it once for it to
>   start working. Note that this only
>   applies to new installations and it
>   will only happen once.)
>
> If that doesn't work then if no custom
>   spell checker have been installed on
>   the computer, exit Word, and then
>   backup and delete the following
>   registry key:
>
> ```
> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\SharedTools\ProofingTools\1.0\Override\en-US
> ```
>
> This key will be rebuilt the next time you start Word.

[Source](http://forums.techarena.in/ms-office-support/734509.htm)

Comment: I dont have Override\en-US. But I have 2 entries inside 1.0: Custom dictionaries, Office. What should I do?

Comment: obviously, you DO have custom dictionaries installed, then DON'T delete this key.

Comment: Then what should I do to make my spelling check work?

Comment: do you have the MSO Installation disk? then run a repair installation.

Answer (score 1):

It could be that the text language is not set to English.

In Word text has a language, just like it has a font and a color and a font size.

Select the entire document (Ctrl+A), then go to **Review** and choose **Set Language** from the "Proofing" toolbar. Set the language to English.